# C# Rotate Images From Url's Stored in XML File

Tags: c#

Im trying to monetize a free winform app, basically I want to have 10 images rotate every 5 min in a picture box. I dont want to hard code these into the app, but store the image url's on my server in a xml file.

this is the xml on my server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Advertisements>
    <Ad>
        <ImageUrl1>http://example.com/example.jpg</ImageUrl1>
        <url1>http://example.com</url1>
    </Ad>
    <Ad>
        <ImageUrl2>http://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageUrl2>
        <url2>http://example.com</url2>
    </Ad>
</Advertisements>
```

Im stuck on how to rotate through each node and display the image for 5 min

Tried to find a decent example, but most are for ASP.net

This is the code in my app:

```
XmlTextReader reader = null;
try {
    string xmlURL = "http://example.com/ads.xml";
    reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
    reader.MoveToContent();
    string elementName = "";
    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) &&
    (reader.Name == "Advertisements")) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            elementName = reader.Name;
            else {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) &&
                (reader.HasValue)) {
                    switch (elementName)
                    {
                        case "ImageUrl1":
                            picturebox.ImageLocation=reader.Value);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception) {
}
finally {
    if (reader != null) reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried please. Most of us don't want to do your **WHOLE** job for you...

Comment: this is what I've tried ( edited it)

Comment: Thx for adding your current code! I also want to point out though that you XML schema may be awkward to parse because you are using different element names within a collection. Don't use `ImageUrl1`, `ImageUrl2`, etc. You should just use `ImageUrl` and be consistent in every element.

Comment: Ok, so just use `ImageUrl`, what would be the best way to jump to the next node to rotate the pic?

Comment: Also, the term "rotate", when speaking about images, usually refers to the action of turning an image on it's side or upside-down. When talking about the action of continually switching between images from a larger set, usually the verb "cycle" is preferred. Your question would likely be better titled: "Cycle Through Images Stored in XML File".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code uses the older `XmlReader` approach to parsing XML manually. This is usually complex and tricky to get right. If you are using .NET version 3.5 or higher, you can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for a cleaner interface to working with XML.

The approach I would take to solving your problem is this:

- On app start-up, load the list of Advertisements from the server and cache the result in a static variable
- Shuffle the list once (after loading it), so you can just keep iterating over the list when picking a new Ad to show (no need to randomize)
- Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to rotate the image every 5 minutes

Here is some sample C# code using LINQ to XML for loading your XML data:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace StackOverflowQ21588436
{
    public class Example
    {
        private const string XML =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Advertisements>
    <Ad>
        <ImageUrl>http://example.com/example.jpg</ImageUrl>
        <url>http://example.com</url>
    </Ad>
    <Ad>
        <ImageUrl>http://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageUrl>
        <url>http://example.com/2.html</url>
    </Ad>
</Advertisements>";

        public static IList<Advertisement> GetAdvertisements()
        {
            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(XML); // or XDocument.Load(url)
            var adXmlNodes = xmlDocument.Element("Advertisements").Elements("Ad");
            var adList = adXmlNodes.Select(xmlNode => new Advertisement {
                ImageUrl = xmlNode.Element("ImageUrl").Value,
                Href = xmlNode.Element("url").Value
            }).ToList();
            return adList;
        }
    }

    public class Advertisement
    {
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; } // named 'Href' to show property names don't have to match XML
    }
}
```